# Is there a way in Slick2D to transform the whole graphics context to monochrome?

Tags: graphics, transform, lwjgl, slick2d, monochrome

I need that effect and I wondered how to do that. I searched on Google but didnt find anything at all that fits my needs.

In particular, I want to draw tiles and wondered if there is a way to transform the graphics contexet they were drawn to to monochrome or if there is any drawing mode for that.

Is there maybe even a way to transform to monochrome to a certain degree? Like to make it 50 percent monochrome, like a new layer. But it would be already very usefull if I knew how to simply transform everything drawn to the graphics context completely to monochrome (black and white).

I tried this:

```
//draw things on screen

GL11.glPixelTransferf(GL11.GL_RED_SCALE, 0.30f);
GL11.glPixelTransferf(GL11.GL_GREEN_SCALE, 0.59f);
GL11.glPixelTransferf(GL11.GL_BLUE_SCALE, 0.11f);

copyArea(container, screenCapture, 0, 0, GL11.GL_LUMINANCE8);

//draw copied area on screen

public void copyArea(GameContainer c, Image target, int x, int y, int format) {
  target.bind();
  GL11.glCopyTexImage2D(SGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, x, c.getHeight()
        - (y + target.getHeight()), target.getTexture().getTextureWidth(), 
        target.getTexture().getTextureHeight(), 0);
  target.ensureInverted();
}
```

But (of course) it was very slow, as it transforms the graphics, then copies it, resets the graphics and renders the copied image of the graphics context.

Thanks for any help or advice in advance.

Comment: This question is very broad and unclear. Can you describe more concisely what it is you're trying to do? Also, can you show the code you have that's causing you a problem?

Comment: There's no code thats causing any problems, there is no problem. And I do realize that it is a very broad question, but I've oretty much already said everything that is to say about this. I want to transform everything that was drawn to the graphics context to a monochrome style, like black and white (maybe setting the saturation somehow to zero?). There is a way to set the image colors with .setImageColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) to make them darker, but thats not really what I want. I want a real monochrome effect, not just darker Images.

Comment: If you've searched Google for conversion to grayscale or desaturation and haven't found anything, you aren't trying very hard. It's a very simple technique described on hundreds pages.

Comment: Well, I did that, more than once.. and I indeed have found some ways but all of them make everything lag when implemented, as most just copy the graphics transform it and render it again.

Comment: Ah! So that's the clarification I was asking for in my first comment. You've implemented it but it was slow. It sounded like you just wanted someone to write it for you. Can you post the implementation you have that's slow? We can probably point out ways to make it faster.

Comment: Added it to my question @user1118321

Comment: Can you post the contents of `copyArea()`?

Comment: Its basically just from there: http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4531&view=next

Comment: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter10.html

Comment: How big is the image you're working with? Using a simple fragment shader applied to a quad with a video frame as the texture, you can easily convert HD video to grayscale in realtime (60 frames per second at 1080p, for example). Are your frames bigger than 1920x1080? If not, you should be able to do the same. Are you reading the results back into main memory?

Comment: No I am not working with frame bigger than 1920x1080 and I dont think that I am reading them back as you say, but I am not sure what you mean by that.